# How to rerun ADF from Failed Pipeline Activity within conditional?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Pipeline that has failed to run on an activity that sits inside of an "If Condition".

It seems possible to rerun the Pipeline from the If but as there are multiple activities that sit inside this (prior to the failed); ideally I would want to rerun the pipeline from the actual failed one.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to rerun the pipeline from the point of failure. In ADF go to monitor pipeline and click on the particular pipeline. Now, you can see where your pipeline is failed it allows you rerun from that.

[image]

It is your choice to rerun the total pipeline or to rerun from a particular activity by **skipping the activities** before it. If your click on any activity it will show the rerun icon on it by which you can rerun the pipeline from that activity even it is succeeded.

Please refer this [Official Microsoft blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/rerun-activities-inside-your-data-factory-pipelines/?ocid=AID754288&wt.mc_id=CFID0427) by **Gaurav Malhotra** to learn more about re-running pipeline from a particular activity.

Also, Please find the similar ask on MS Q&A answered by **nasreen-akter**:

[ADF rerun or restart from point of failure - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/210183/adf-rerun-or-restart-from-point-of-failure.html#:%7E:text=In%20the%20ADF%2C%20there%20is%20no%20easy%20way,of%20that%20activity%20failure%20%28please%20see%20the%20screenshot%29.)